# Как выбрать элемент, при условии нахождения его в 2-х списках?

Tags: python, list, if

Имеются списки:

```
a = ['qwe', 'rty', 'uio']
b = dict.key()
# в ключах могут быть слова как из списка [а] так и нет
```

Задача: выбрать из некого третьего списка, прилетающего на вход, слова, которые есть в списке ***а*** и ключах словаря ***b*** и к ним применить некое действие.

Answer (score 4):

Если рассматривать переменные `a`, `c` и ключи словаря `b` как множества, тогда задача сводится к нахождению пересечения трех множеств.

Для примера воспользуемся переменными из ответа уважаемого CrazyElf:

```
res = set(a) & set(b) & set(c)
```

результат:

```
In [27]: res
Out[27]: {'uio'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто через `in` проверяете и наличие элемента в списке и наличие элемента в ключах словаря:

```
a = ['qwe', 'rty', 'uio']
b = {'qwe':'asd', 'uio':'zxc'}
c = ['ghj','uio','123','rty']
for x in c:
    if x in a and x in b:
        print('делаем что-то с', x)
```

Вывод:

```
делаем что-то с uio
```

А по вашему коду:

- `dict` - плохое название для словаря, оно перекрывает класс `dict`
- функция взятия ключей словаря называется `keys()`, а не `key()`
- обращение к `.keys()` в большинстве случаев не нужно - когда вы итерируетесь по ключам по словаря или проверяете через `in` вхождение чего-то в ключи словаря, `.keys()` можно не писать, обращение и так будет к ключам словаря